# React Context is not working as expected: Unable to change the value of shared variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-context, react-three-fiber

I made a context to share the value of the variable "clicked" throughout my nextjs pages, it seems to give no errors but as you can see the variable's value remains FALSE even after the click event. It does not change to TRUE. This is my first time working with context, what am I doing wrong?
I'm using typescript
PS: After the onClick event the log's number shoots up by 3 or 4, is it being executed more than once, but how?

*controlsContext.tsx*

```
import { createContext, FC, useState } from "react";

export interface MyContext {
    clicked: boolean;
    changeClicked?: () => void;
}

const defaultState = {
  clicked: false,
}

const ControlContext = createContext<MyContext>(defaultState);


export const ControlProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [clicked, setClicked] =  useState(defaultState.clicked);
    const changeClicked = () => setClicked(!clicked);
  return (
    <ControlContext.Provider
      value={{
          clicked,
          changeClicked,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ControlContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ControlContext;
```

*Model.tsx*

```
import ControlContext from "../contexts/controlsContext";

export default function Model (props:any) { 
    const group = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null!)
    const {clicked, changeClicked } = useContext(ControlContext);

    const handleClick = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        //e.preventDefault();
        changeClicked();
        console.log(clicked);
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(clicked);
      }, [clicked]);
    useFrame((state, delta) => (group.current.rotation.y += 0.01));
    const model = useGLTF("/scene.gltf ");
    return (
        <>
        
         <TransformControls enabled={clicked}>
         
        <mesh 
            ref={group} 
            {...props}
            scale={clicked ? 0.5 : 0.2}
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            <primitive object={model.scene}/>
        </mesh>
        </TransformControls>
        
        </>
    )
}
```

*_app.tsx*

```
import {ControlProvider} from '../contexts/controlsContext';


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ControlProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} 
      />
    </ControlProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

[image: This is the error I get]

Comment: in your attached image, you still have `changeClicked` instead of `changeClicked()`...

Comment: @andymccullough My bad, I forgot to update the image, please refer to the latest one now

Comment: you also have `;;` at the end of the line `const changeClicked ...`

Comment: @andymccullough I've refactored my code, please check it once above. Now when a click event happens, such an error pops up

Comment: It seems at this point we just need more context and more complete code to see what and where these components are rendered and how they relate. Can you create a *running* codesandbox so we can inspect and debug it without playing 20 questions? For example, what is `Component` in `MyApp`? Is the `Modal` rendered within the context provider? Etc...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-zhukovsky-8lkmn1?file=/pages/index.tsx

@DrewReese
Here, please do have a look, I'll be really grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

1. You are not actually invoking the `changeClicked` callback.
2. React state updates are asynchronously processed, so you can't log the state being updated in the same callback scope as the enqueued update, it will only ever log the state value from the current render cycle, not what it will be in a subsequent render cycle.
3. You've listed the `changeClicked` callback as optional, so Typescript will warn you if you don't use a null-check before calling `changeClicked`.

## Solution

```
const { clicked, changeClicked } = useContext(ControlContext);

...

<mesh 
  ...
  onClick={(event) => {
    changeClicked && changeClicked();
  }}
>
  ...
</mesh>

...
```

Or declare the `changeClicked` as required in call normally. You are already providing `changeClicked` as part of the default context value, and you don't conditionally include in in the provider, so there's no need for it to be optional.

```
export interface MyContext {
  clicked: boolean,
  changeClicked: () => void
}
```

...

```
const { clicked, changeClicked } = useContext(ControlContext);

...

<mesh 
  ...
  onClick={(event) => {
    changeClicked();
  }}
>
  ...
</mesh>

...
```

Use an `useEffect` hook in to log any state updates.

```
const { clicked, changeClicked } = useContext(ControlContext);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(clicked);
}, [clicked]);
```

#### Update

After working with you and your sandbox it needed a few tweaks.

1. Wrapping the `index.tsx` JSX code with the `ControlProvider` provider component so there was a valid context value being provided to the app. The UI here had to be refactored into a React component so it could itself ***also*** consume the context value.
2. It seems there was some issue with the HTML canvas element, or the `mesh` element that was preventing the `Modal` component from maintaining a "solid" connection with the React context. It wasn't overtly clear what the issue was here, but passing the context values directly to the `Modal` component as props resolved the issue with the `changeClicked` callback becoming undefined.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I made the necessary changes and there's no error. But it still doesn't work, whenever I click the mesh, the event isn't triggered.  As a proof, I tried your useEffect solution to log the changes but it only triggers once after the component is mounted, it doesn't trigger after that, meaning that the value of "clicked" isn't being changed

Comment: @sbunn Does `mesh` handle click events? Does something simple like `<mesh ... onClick={() => console.log("mesh clicked")}> ....</mesh>` result in the console log? Think you could create a pared down, *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Yes, `mesh` handles click events. I have shared a code sandbox with you, but there are some errors regarding react popping up in that :(

Comment: @sbunn Sorry, am I missing where you've shared a code sandbox link?

Comment: I've refactored my code, please check it once above. Now when a click event happens, such an error pops up

Comment: @sbunn Welcome, glad to assist. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A few things -

```
setClicked((prev) => !prev);
```

instead of

```
setClicked(!clicked);
```

As it ensures it's not using stale state. Then you are also doing -

```
changeClicked
```

But it should be -

```
changeClicked();
```

Lastly, you cannot `console.log(clicked)` straight after calling the set state function, it will be updated in the next render

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! However when I change changeClicked to changeClicked(), I get an error
``
onClick={(event) => {
                changeClicked();
            }}
``

The error - **Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)**

Comment: Your interface has changeClicked as optional, so either make it not optional or check it exists before calling it

Comment: I made the necessary changes, however changeClicked is not triggered anytime. The value of the variable "clicked" remains false :(